# quit iframe html element?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am developing a html5 game app and I have two sections in my page, the menu and the game, which is in iframe.
when I open the app just the menu appears and if I click play' the menu is hidden (with jquery) and it writes in the Game section the iframe element:
(`<iframe src="Game.html class="GameFrame" ></iframe>`)
also in jquery.
Now, the problem is that I cannot find a way to quit the iframe and show again the menu section.
Has anybody an idea?
Thank you,
Boaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to access parent `window` from inner `iframe`. Use `window.parent` to access parent window.

If you have jQuery in parent window, you can access it by `window.parent.$` from inner iframe and from there you know how to show/hide things.

For example:

(in iframe)

```
window.parent.$('#menu').hide();
```